# Filter base of multiple columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

is there a way to filter values of one column present in 3 other columns?

One long solution is to do this

```
filter(Names1 %in% Names2| Names1 %in% Names3| Names1 %in% Names4)
```

is there a faster way to do it with dplyr?

something like this

```
filter(Names1 %in% (Names2| Names3 | Names4)
```

Thanks

I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `c()` to combine the columns you are looking in:

```
df %>%
  filter(Names1 %in% c(Names2, Names3, Names4))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `subset`

```
subset(df, Names1 %in% c(Names2, Names3, Names4))
```